# Decoding complex JSON response in Swift using JSONDecoder and Generics

Tags: swift, generics, codable, jsondecoder

I'm dealing with API responses that typically look like the example below.
So some basic data as wrapper and then the detailresponse, made up by count as well as whatever objects get returned by the API, subject to the endpoint I'm calling. In the example below, it's 3 conversation objects.

```
{
 "statuscode": 200,
    "response_type": 3,
    "errormessage": null,
    "detailresponse": {
        "count": 3,
        "conversations": [
           {...},
           {...},
           {...}
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm Decoding Data with JSONDecoder. As the wrapper is always the same and the contained object changes, subject to the called endpoint, I'm using the below decoding setup.

1) A struct representing the wrapper + Generics for the detailresponse:

```swift
struct ResponseMultipleElements<T1: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let statuscode: Int
    let response_type: Int
    let errormessage: String?
    let detailresponse: Element<T1>

}

// Below custom key decoding strategy will map any CodingKey but "count" in api detailresponse to fixed value "element".
// This enables reusability by allowing detailresponse to host any custom data type without this surrounding structure having to know it
struct Element<T2: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let count: Int
    let element: T2
}

struct AnyCodingKey: CodingKey {

    var stringValue: String
    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int? { return nil }
    init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }
}
```

2) A custom decoding strategy that skips over count in the detailresponse and maps the contained object

```swift
func getConversations(completion: @escaping(Result<[Conversation], APIError>) -> Void) {

        {...} //basic URLRequest and dataTask configuraation

             do {
                 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                 decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom { codingKeys in
                     let lastKey = codingKeys.last!
                     if lastKey.intValue != nil || codingKeys.count != 2 { return lastKey }
                     if lastKey.stringValue == "count" { return lastKey }
                     return AnyCodingKey(stringValue: "element")!
                 }
                 let result = try decoder.decode(ResponseMultipleElements<[Conversation]>.self, from: data!)
                 completion(.success(result.detailresponse.element))
             }catch {
                print("Error is: ", error)
                completion(.failure(.decodingError))
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

The Conversation Class in the above example looks like this:

```swift
class Conversation: Codable {

    var id: Int?
    var participants: [User]?
    var tsp: String? // TODO: handle dates - currently just strings
    var lastactivity: String?

}
```

This worked great up until the point where I was presented with an API response that holds to objects in the detailresponse - here's an example:

```
{
 "statuscode": 200,
    "response_type": 3,
    "errormessage": null,
    "detailresponse": {
        "count": 4,
        "messages": [
           {...},
           {...},
           {...},
           {...}
         ],
         "conversation_participants": [
           {...}
         ]
    }
}
```

The ChatMessage Class in the above example looks like this:

```swift
class ChatMessage: Codable {

    var id: Int?
    var sender: User?
    var message: String?
    var seen: Bool?
    var tsp: String? // TODO: handle dates - currently just strings

}
```

MY QUESTION:

I'm struggling to understand how I need to adjust my setup, the classes / structs ChatMessage and ResponseMultipleElements in particular, in order to successfully decode responses containing 2 objects (like the example with message and conversation_participants above).

Many thanks for your input!!!

Comment: My custom `keyDecodingStrategy` assumes – and is based on – that there is only **one** arbitrary key (apart from `count`) in `detailresponse`. If the name of the second key is static it's quite easy to change the key decoding strategy. With a second dynamic key I don't see any solution at the moment.

Comment: @vadian: What would be the fix, assuming the key for the second object would always be "conversation_participants"?

Comment: Replace the line `if lastKey.stringValue == "count" { return lastKey }` with `if lastKey.stringValue == "count" || lastKey.stringValue == "conversation_participants" { return lastKey }`. The type can be generic.

Comment: @vadian: But wouldn't that only skip over "conversation_participants" key? I'd like to get hold of both objects, the messages as well as the conversation_participants.

Comment: It does not skip the key, returning `lastKey` means it does not **change** the key

Comment: @vadian: OK, I understand that. What I don't understand is if / how I can decode the conversation_participants array into the messages object so I can access the data it contains. Many thanks for your help so far!!!

Comment: Declare a member `conversation_participants` in `Element`

Comment: @vadian: Would you be able to show me the solution? It might be obvious to you but I struggle to embrace this one. I've tried this `struct Element<T2: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let count: Int
    let element: T2
    let conversation_participants: User?
}` but I get "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead." Also, with this, wouldn't conversation_participants be part of "detaialresponse" rather than being decoded to be part of a ChatMessage struct?

Comment: It's `let conversation_participants: [User]?` since the object is an array. The message *Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead* is very clear.